# Informal description of Non-deterministic TM for the language $L = \{w^n \mid w \in \{a, b\}^* \text{ and } n \geq 2\}$

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, automata, nondeterminism

From a list of practice problems for a graduate Theory of Computation course. I've done quite a few problems at this point on deterministic Turing Machines, I just don't think I have fully grasped the notion of non-determinism in the context of TM's yet.

I suppose this TM would work *something* like this: Given an input $x$, non-deterministically try different divisions of $x$. For instance, if $x$ was of length 10, $x$ could be divided as $w_1w_2$ or $w_1w_2w_3w_4w_5$. Then, for each "guess" check if each of the substrings is the same.

I understand this is in and of itself an "informal description," but I would like to include some more "implementation-level" details. Some things that are confusing me... How can we be sure that the possible subdivisions of $x$ where the number of subdivisions does not divide the length of $x$ will not accept? For instance, in my example, how can we enure that the "guess" of $w_1w_2w_3$ will not accept? Furthermore, how can we go about the actual process of ensuring each $w_i$ are equal? I am familiar with the construction of the TM for $L = \{ww \mid w \in \{a, b\}^*\}$ where you first mark the midpoint with a $\#$, but I am not sure how you would mark the subdivision points when there can be an arbitrary number of substrings.

Anyway, hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When "marking a letter" on the Turing tape, we replace a symbol $a$ by another symbol, like $X$, $\bar a$, or $\underline a$. Since various markings might be needed it is practically more convenient to consider a tape with various parallel components. We may write on each of these components to record phases of the computation.

The first $w$ can be guessed by marking its last position on the tape. Then is is straightforward to check whether the next segment also equals $w$. Just match the letters of $w$ one by one with the letters of the next segment. The machine marks the letters that have been checked. When everything is OK, unmark initial $w$ and repeat for the next segment. Etcetera, until the final segment is empty.

We accept if the segments match. In case the length of the string is not a multiple of $|w|$ the machine will be unable to match the final segment with initial $w$.

Final point. You state "non-deterministically try different divisions". Technically a deterministic machine would try various divisions. A non-deterministic machine tries only one. If there is a way to guess right, the string will be accepted.